# Prevent PySide2 dialog from closing when QRunnable still running

Tags: python, pyside2

I have a PySide2 application where I'm executing a long running process using `QRunnable` and I don't want the user to accidentally close the dialog until the finished signals is emitted.

While I can use `self.setWindowFlag(QtCore.Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint, False)` and re-enable it after the `QRunnable` finished running, I prefer to have a way alert the user that the function is still running if they accidentally close it (despite the dialog showing a progress bar and output log).

I'm thinking of subclassing and override the closeEvent but I wonder if there is other or even better way to approach this problem.

Comment: No, the close event override is the preferred choice. The alternative is to install an event filter on the window and detect close events, which is conceptually the same thing.

Comment: @musicamante Thanks for the comment. I ended up with the close event override and got it to work. I'll post a working sample example later here.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example of a closeEvent override that satisfy the need of my original question.

```py
import sys

from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
from PySide2.QtCore import *


class CloseEventOverrideDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowFlag(Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint, True)
        self.setWindowFlag(Qt.WindowMaximizeButtonHint, True)
        self.setWindowTitle("closeEvent Override Example")

        self.is_busy = False

        self.setup_ui()

    def closeEvent(self, event: QCloseEvent):
        print(f"{self.is_busy=}")
        if self.is_busy:
            msg = (
                f"Something is busy running. Do you wish to abort the progress?"
            )
            is_cancel = QMessageBox.warning(
                self,
                "Warning!",
                msg,
                QMessageBox.Ok,
                QMessageBox.Cancel
            )
            print(f"{is_cancel=}")
            if is_cancel == QMessageBox.Cancel:
                # Prevent dialog from closing!
                event.ignore()
            else:
                print(f"User explicitly close dialog!")
                event.accept()

    def setup_ui(self):
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        checked_label = QLabel(
            "Checked the following checkbox to trigger a QMessageBox Warning dialog "
            "when user close the dialog."
        )
        self.layout.addWidget(checked_label)

        self.busy_checkbox = QCheckBox("Busy")
        self.busy_checkbox.stateChanged.connect(self.toggle_is_busy)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.busy_checkbox)

    def toggle_is_busy(self):
        self.is_busy = True if self.busy_checkbox.isChecked() else False
        print(f"{self.is_busy=}")


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = CloseEventOverrideDialog()
    dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[Screenshot of QMessageBox Warning when user tries to close the dialog with closeEvent override](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0SIP.png)